# How to get a clear blurred background in android?

Tags: android, bitmap

I am using ScriptIntrinsicBlur  for blurring Bitmap . But I am not getting the background as i like .
  Code :

```
  public  Bitmap BlurImage(Bitmap input, Context ctx) {
       try {
             RenderScript rsScript = RenderScript.create(ctx);
             Allocation alloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rsScript, input);

             ScriptIntrinsicBlur blur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rsScript, Element.U8_4(rsScript));
                        blur.setRadius(radius);
                        blur.setInput(alloc);

             Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(input.getWidth(), input.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
             Allocation outAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rsScript, result);

             blur.forEach(outAlloc);
             outAlloc.copyTo(result);

             rsScript.destroy();
             return result;
          } catch (Exception e) {
              // TODO: handle exception
              return input;
          }

  }
```

See these Samples Images : 
1st  one is how i get the background.

2nd one is how i need the background.

![How I am getting the background : I am just scaling the bitmap to smaller    pixels and then sending to the code above to blur it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGIEs.jpg)

[image: how i need the background : screenshot is from gaana app(see the background)]

Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this library, it will give you the result you wanted.

-> [android-stackblur](https://github.com/kikoso/android-stackblur)